# Whether the IPMI management can not show disk's information?

Tags: supermicro, ipmi

I use the IPMI management check the system information, but there only shows the System, BIOS, CPU and DIMM. there is no disk information there.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So, whether the BMC can not get disk information?